# Merge crosstab tag into pivot

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, tag-synonyms

[pivot](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pivot) has 131 questions and [crosstab](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crosstab) has 12.

**Are the two tags similar enough to be merged?**

Or is there any important difference between the two from a [tagging perspective](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32041/194636)?

If you think the tags are different, please add your reasoning to the '**No**' CW answer below.

If you agree the tags should be merged, vote '**Yes**'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes**, [crosstab](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crosstab) **should be a synonym** of [pivot](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pivot) and **merged**.

Any product-specific differences are indicated by the product tag.

#### Update

A synonym has been created.
[crosstab](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crosstab) has been removed from 9 questions.
[pivot](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pivot) has been added to 4 questions.
Tag merge completed.

Answer (score -6):

**No**, the [crosstab](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crosstab) tag **should remain separate** from [pivot](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pivot) because...